# Does Twitter's rate limits affect an app's status update ability to it's connected users?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I have done lots and lots of reading on twitters documentation, and I am just triple checking!
I have read that Twitter's [rate limits](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting) do not affect [posting statuses](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/update) on authenticated users *(i.e. user connects with web app and they authorise a status post to their profile from the web app.)* through an app except for and only if the user themselves have reached their [own limits](http://support.twitter.com/forums/10711/entries/15364)?

Is the correct and can someone please confirm this?

Comment: Have you asked Twitter yet?  I bet they will know...

Comment: I read their documentation, it's been a long day and I am just making sure i have understood it before proceeding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. There are two separate API limits, an IP-based one and a user-based one. If you're making an authenticated request, the user's limit gets used. If you're making an anonymous request, the IP's limit gets used.

Comment: So the application isn't limited in updating the authenticated users status only the user themselves are? The application would only be limited in GET requests in general? - Makes sense as it's the constant posting and following that is the pulse of twitter!

Comment: Right. If you're doing a mass-post to lots of Twitter accounts, you shouldn't hit any IP limits.

Comment: excellent, thanks very much for your quick answer! - (will accept when it lets me in 6 mins)